# Recorrer List asp.net from Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

genero en codigo la siguiente lista:

```
[WebMethod()]
    public static List<CustomerBCP> allValues()
    {

        var list = new List<CustomerBCP>();
        CustomerBCP employee1 = new CustomerBCP()
        {
            CustomerNumber = "Sathya",
            SalesOrder = "10",
            Status = "Chennai"
        };
        CustomerBCP employee2 = new CustomerBCP()
        {
            CustomerNumber = "Ram",
            SalesOrder = "11",
            Status = "Chennai"
        };
        CustomerBCP employee3 = new CustomerBCP()
        {
            CustomerNumber = "Pandi",
            SalesOrder = "12",
            Status = "Chennai"
        };
        CustomerBCP employee4 = new CustomerBCP()
        {
            CustomerNumber = "Karthick",
            SalesOrder = "13",
            Status = "Chennai"
        };
        list.Add(employee1);
        list.Add(employee2);
        list.Add(employee3);
        list.Add(employee4);

        return list; }
```

Y en mi funcion de Ajax tengo lo siguiente:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'Default.aspx/allValues',
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function (data)
            {

                console.log(data.d + '***');

                $.each(data, function () {
                    $.each(this, function (k, v) {
                        console.log(k + '**' + v);
                    });
                });

            },
            error: function (x, y) {
                console.log(x);
            }
```

La lista si esta pasando valores, pero no he podido lograr obtener los valores con jquery, el mensaje que se muestra como `console.log(data.d + '***');` me esta retornando lo siguiente:

> [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]***

Comment: ¿y qué te da solo `console.log(data)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener los valores debes invocarlos de la siguiente manera:

```
var dData = JSON.stringify(data.d['0']);
data = JSON.parse(dData);
```

tu código debería quedar así:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'Default.aspx/allValues',
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function (data)
            {
                var dData = JSON.stringify(data.d['0']);
                data = JSON.parse(dData);

                console.log(data + '***');

                $.each(data, function () {
                    $.each(this, function (k, v) {
                        console.log(k + '**' + v);
                    });
                });

            },
            error: function (x, y) {
                console.log(x);
            }
```

Solo se aplica un doble parseo para una lectura natural de los datos.

Si tienes dudas, consulta.

Answer (score 0):

me ayudo mucho este link.

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Return-JSON-data-object-from-WebMethod-PageMethod-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Por si a alguien mas le puede apoyar.

Saludos